# Lambda Binding Expression for Array

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am currently working on writing dynamic select clause using Lambda Expressions and stuck at a point where I have to deal with nested collections. For example

```
class A
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<B> Property3 {get;set;}
}

class B
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public int Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

I have class A and B as shown above and I get collection of A however as this data within A is going to get binded to grid, all properties are not required. Its like view dependent. View defines fields to display. Hence I am creating object on the fly and adds required properties to it. This I have done using Lambda Expression as shown below,

```
Expression.Bind(p, Expression.PropertyOrField(entityExpression, p.Name))
```

This works if I have to select only Property1 and Property2 from class A, however if I want Property3 which is collection, it will not work as I am creating type on the fly and just adding required properties to it. Hence at run  time i will have scenario like

```
IEnumerable<RuntimeType2> => RuntimeType2 { string Prop1 {get;set; }
IEnumberable<RuntimeType1> => 
RuntimeType1 { string Property1 {get;set;
IEnumerable<RuntimeType2> Property3 {get;set;} }
```

Above is scenario which I want to achieve. For simple case I am able to do this however I am struggling to bind to collection.

I hope my problem has enough description. If you need more information please reply. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why doesn't creating the collection property work? What *does* it do (exception?)?

Comment: Yes the types are different, problem is I am not able to specify property mapping using Expressio.Bind eg like I have mentioned above mapping of Prop1 of class B to Prop1 of RuntimeType2

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to push a value of type `IEnumerable<B>` into a property with type `IEnumerable<RuntimeType2>`. You have to convert between the two by using a nested select (that you have to create using the Expression API to call the `Enumerable.Select` method).